# C macro wrapping

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

So I encountered the following code in a library for C for RF communication :

```
#define __COMB(a,b,c) (a##b##c)
#define _COMB(a,b,c) __COMB(a,b,c)
```

Which is basically used to create various names for constants and functions. It just concatenates the parameters.

What I don't get is the 2nd line. Is there a reason to wrap the macro?
If it's just a naming issue, why not just write :

```
#define _COMB(a,b,c) (a##b##c)
```

The library can be found [here](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/VirtualWire/index.html).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to expand the macro variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a hack to trick the C preprocessor to pre-expand the parameters before they're concatenated. This kind of decoupling is required in certain some situations, for example if `__COMB` is to be used in a preprocessor macro parameter stringification.

Comment: This might be stupid, but what exactly does pre-expand the parameters mean?

Comment: @parakmiakos That is, if `a`, `b` or `c` are macros themselves, then to expand them first before concatenating.

Comment: @BlueMoon So if I were to write something like `_COMB(TIMER,VW_TIMER_INDEX,_COMPA_vect)`, VW_TIMER_INDEX being a macro, without this trick, what would the result be?

Answer (score 2):

Double macro is used to make sure, that it will work even when parameters are also macros.

Without double macro we would get `XXYYZZ` instead of `xyz`:

```
#define XX x
#define YY y
#define ZZ z
_COMB(XX, YY, ZZ)
```